# mysql: Select data from table and group by time slot

Tags: mysql

I have a table consisting of appointments with date, time and a participant.

I now need to select all data from this table and **group it by time slot**, so I can see which appointments are set to which date.
There can be *multiple* participants for one time slot.

**table appointments:**

```
+-----------------+--------+--------------------+
| id | date       | time   | participant        |
+-----------------+--------+--------------------|
| 1  | 2020-01-05 | 08:00  | John Doe           |
| 2  | 2020-01-05 | 08:30  | Steve Jobs         |
| 3  | 2020-01-05 | 08:30  | Max Mustermann     |
| 4  | 2020-02-05 | 11:00  | John Wayne         |
| 5  | 2020-03-05 | 11:00  | Martina Mustermann |
+-----------------+--------+--------------------+
```

I now need to find the query to get a result like this:

```
2020-01-05 - 08:00
- John Doe

2020-01-05 - 08:30
- Steve Jobs
- Max Mustermann 

2020-02-05 - 11:00
- John Wayne

2020-03-05 - 11:00
- Martina Mustermann
```

Of course the result doesn't have to be formatted like this, it's enough for me to find the query itself. Then I'll be able to use php to create an array out of it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: AFAIK, you can't have nested tables. You might need to perform the grouping in the application

Comment: You dont find queries, you write them

Comment: Post your expected results in tabular format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next query will help you:

```
SELECT
 `date`, `time`, GROUP_CONCAT(`participant`)
FROM `your_table`
GROUP BY `date`, `time`;
```

Here [GROUP_CONCAT documentation](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/)